# Issues with calling internal functions in my javascript 'class'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to write some JavaScript to handle a bunch of functions for Google Maps, but in a way that's reusable for multiple maps on one page.

The issue that I'm having is that functions called within functions seem to loose view of the variables declared at the top my my javascript 'class' (I know it's not actually a class).

The **geocodeAddress** function calls Googles geocoder.geocode API function which accepts a function to call with the results as a parameter. Within this result function I have no access to the other properties within my 'class' and all are set to 'undefined'. I also can't call any other functions.

Does anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible or should I give up with this style and just pass the map object around from method to method to make it reusable with other maps?

```
function GoogleMap(settings) {

var map;

this.zoom = settings.zoom;
this.center = new google.maps.LatLng(settings.lat, settings.lng);
this.mapContainerId = settings.mapContainerId;

this.initializeGoogleMap = function initializeGoogleMap(mapOptions) {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapContainerId), { zoom: this.zoom, center: this.center });
}

this.addMapMarker = function addMapMarker(markerOptions) {
    // add a marker here        
}

this.geocodeAddress = function geocodeAddress(location) {
    // I have full access to this.zoom, this.center etc. here
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {

        // this.zoom, this.center etc. are inaccessible here and return undefined.
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            this.addMapMarker({ center: results[0].geometry.location, draggable: true, title: location });
        } else {
            alert('Could not find the address entered');
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this.initializeGoogleMap());
```

};

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're making some invalid assumptions about how `this` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks don't natively preserve the value of `this` for you, so you will need to do something to set it for you.  You can either create a closure variable or use `.bind()` with the callbacks.

Here's one solution using a closure variable `self`:

```
this.geocodeAddress = function geocodeAddress(location) {
    var self = this;
    // I have full access to this.zoom, this.center etc. here
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {

        // this.zoom, this.center etc. are inaccessible here and return undefined.
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            self.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            self.addMapMarker({ center: results[0].geometry.location, draggable: true, title: location });
        } else {
            alert('Could not find the address entered');
        }
    });
}
```

And, a solution using `.bind()`:

```
this.geocodeAddress = function geocodeAddress(location) {
    // I have full access to this.zoom, this.center etc. here
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {

        // this.zoom, this.center etc. are inaccessible here and return undefined.
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            this.addMapMarker({ center: results[0].geometry.location, draggable: true, title: location });
        } else {
            alert('Could not find the address entered');
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Ah such a simple solution! Thanks. It also works with me adding var self = this; at the very top, right after the 'GoogleMap' function declaration.

Comment: @JGDEV - yes, that works because all your methods are declared inside the constructor so they all have access to local variables in the constructor.  That wouldn't work if you were using the prototype for your methods.  Declaring it within the method works either way.